# Circles not bouncing elastically in SpriteKit's physics engine

Tags: ios, swift, physics

I've been messing around with Swift and SpriteKit's physics engine and wanted to make a simple billiards style game. I've got a simple ball/table setup made but when the balls collide with each other or the wall, they lose much of their velocity, even though their friction and linear damping are set to 0 and their restitution is set to 1. Obviously billiard balls have some friction and don't have max restitution, but for my game's sake, I would like to have completely elastic collisions. I've tinkered around with all of the physical properties, and can't find a combination that yields elastic collisions. I've also checked if the walls' physical properties have a say in the matter, and no, they don't. Changing the walls' friction or restitution did not change the results. Thanks for the help!

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    for i in 0...5
    {
        addChild(newBall())
    }

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
}

func newBall() -> SKShapeNode
{
    let radius = CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)+10))
    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
    ball.lineWidth = 1
    ball.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    ball.fillColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    ball.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(400)+50)), CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(220)+50)))

    var body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    ball.physicsBody = body
    body.friction = 0
    body.restitution = 1
    body.linearDamping = 0
    body.allowsRotation = true
    body.velocity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(50)+50)), CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(50)+50)))

    return ball
}
}
```

Comment: Can you somehow visualize the rotation? Linear momentum can and will be exchanged with angular momentum. Or set allowsRotation to false.